# How to construct REST API endpoints with both composite keys and arrays?

Tags: rest

Although there are tons of similar questions regarding the REST API design, I am asking a very specific question that I could not found answers in other similar questions.

Suppose that I am trying to GET a list of devices in the database with `Building_Type` and `Room_Type` filters. I would like to pass an array of filters, and each filter contains two field as a composite key. I've found standard practice to pass parameter arrays, but I could not find a good way for composite keys in the array.
Example:

```
GET /api/v1/devices?building_type=Educational&room_type=Office
```

This GETs all rooms with `Educational` building type and `Office` room type. However, I am trying to get a list of rooms for **multiple composite combinations** of `{building_type, room_type}`.
I am thinking of something like the following:

```
GET /api/v1/devices?location[]={building_type=Educational,room_type=Office}&location[]={building_type=Commercial,room_type=Office}&location[]={building_type=Educational,room_type=Classroom}
```

However this doesn't look like standard practice. **I am asking for a better way to design this endpoint**. I also don't want POST because this query does not change the state
on the server.

Note:
Please note that the following is incorrect, because I need to filter by **an array of composite attributes** of `{building_type, room_type}`.

```
GET /api/v1/devices?building_type[]=Educational&building_type[]=Commercial&room_type[]=Office&room_type=Classroom
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what your backend can handle, but I would try an array of objects, like:

```
GET /api/v1/devices?location[][building_type]=Educational&location[][room_type]=Office&location[][building_type]=Commercial&location[][room_type]=ClassRoom
```

Rails 6 parses this like I expect:

```
"location"=>[{"building_type"=>"Education", "room_type"=>"Office"}, {"building_type"=>"Commercial", "room_type"=>"ClassRoom"}]
```

But, as [this article](https://blog.shalvah.me/posts/fun-stuff-representing-arrays-and-objects-in-query-strings) goes into, libraries don't handle complex object serialization/deserialization into query params consistently. If your backend doesn't like the above, numerically indexing the array should work (though it's more work to construct from your client code):

```
GET /api/v1/devices?location[0][building_type]=Educational&location[0][room_type]=Office&location[1][building_type]=Commercial&location[1][room_type]=ClassRoom
```

If you want something that won't be implementation-dependent, you could also consider URL-encoding a JSON string that represents your search query:

```
GET /api/v1/devices?query=%7B%22locations%22%3A%20%5B%7B%22building_type%22%3A%20%22Educational%22%2C%20%22room_type%22%3A%20%22Office%22%7D%2C%20%7B%20%22building_type%22%3A%20%22Commercial%22%2C%20%22room_type%22%3A%20%22Office%22%7D%5D%7D
```

Not pretty, but possibly less frustrating.

Comment: I am implementing the backend myself with Express.js. Is Exprees.js able to properly deserialize your example, or do I have to implement it myself? Do you know any library that can properly deserialize this type of complex queries?

Comment: I believe express uses https://github.com/ljharb/qs, which can definitely handle the numeric-indexed version, but you’ll need to experiment to see if it handles the first option correctly or not. Though, if you’re interested in choosing an option that’s close to a standard, the numeric indexes are probably the way to go

Comment: One more question: in this example, do you think I should use plural form `locations` or just stick to one way of implementation? The plural-singular conversion is tiresome and prone to bugs in complex queries.

Comment: I'd go with plural, since it makes it clearer it's an array and not a singular value.